# How to edit HTML Form text box using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to edit HTML form text box using Javascript.

I want the HTML text box to initially display "Enter your name here", and as soon as the user clicks on the box, I want the text box to go blank, so that the user does not have to delete the "Enter your name here" text before actually entering her name.

How do I go on about doing that?

This is what I have tried, without any success.

```
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function name()

            {
                window.document.getElementById("name").value='';
            }

    </script>

    Your Name:<input type="text" value="Enter Your Name Here" id="name" onclick="name();">
</body>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `placeholder` in your input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called a placeholder, and in HTML5 you have a attribute on `input` for that:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name Here" />
```

See how it works in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zMzg8/).

Comment: Hi Patrick, Well, the answer does what I wanted to do. I didn't know about Placeholder. Thanks.

It's just that I was waiting to see if anyone could also do it with JS too.

Comment: You can, but you don't want to.

Comment: See this one for example: http://www.scriptiny.com/2012/08/html5-placeholder-fallback-using-jquery/, or this one: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text.

Comment: Thank. The second one had what I wanted to see. Just for curiosity, of course placeholders are better option.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to use the 'placeholder' attribute of the textbox:

`<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name Here" id="name">`

This will give you the desired effect (i.e. disappearing text on user click).

Answer (score 0):

use

```
     window.document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = #value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the placeholder attribute of input tag.

Sample:
`<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name">`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     function name()
>
>         {
>             window.document.getElementById("name").value='';
>         }
>
> </script>
>
> Your Name:<input type="text" value="Enter Your Name Here" id="name" onclick="javascript: name();"> </body>
> ```